# Rails webcal subcription url with user authentication token;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar

I am trying to create a link for user of my app to use to subscribe to their account calendars. I have a link that works that I generate in rails    calendar_publisher_lists_url(:format => :ics, :only_path => false,:protocol => "web cal")
which generates a link like webcal://mywebsite.com/calendar.ics
However this only works if the user is logged in. I need for the link to work when the calendar is automatically updated, even if the user is not logged in. Thus I need to generate a link that would look like:
webcal://123@mywebsite.com/calendar.ics where '123' is the authentication token for the user. 
How do I generate this url?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with putting it onto the URL as attribute?

```
calendar_publisher_lists_url(:format => :ics, :only_path => false,:protocol => "webcal", :authentication_token => current_user.authentication_token)

webcal://mywebsite.com/calendar.ics?authentication_token=123
```

I mean apart from the security issue...

Comment: This is great.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue you could change the route to add an id.

```
match '/calendar/:id/calendar_feed', to: 'calendar#calendar_feed', :as => 'calendar_feed_path'
```

Then in your controller put

```
def calendar_feed
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.ics
  end
end
```

And then add a view template, adjust to fit your needs with your logic (this code is from one of my projects):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//UserCalendar//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Name Of Website
CALSCALE:GERGORIAN
<% @users.each do |user| %>  #change logic to fit your needs
    <% user.day_offs.each do |day_off| %>
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:<%=Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")%>
UID:<%=day_off.id%>
SUMMARY:<%= day_off.user.name.titleize %> | <%= day_off.do_type %>
DTSTART:<%= day_off.start_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") %>
<% end_day=day_off.end_date + 1.day %>
DTEND:<%= end_day.strftime("%Y%m%d") %>
END:VEVENT
<% end %>
<% end %>
END:VCALENDAR
```

Then the feed link would be

```
<%= link_to("Subscribe to Calendar", "webcal://www.nameofwebsite.com/calendar_feed/#{current_user.user_id}/calendar_feed.ics" ) %>
```